# Get cell value from specified column in a Gridview upon "RowUpdating" Event ASP.NET/VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

What i want to do is te following... i have a gridview that loads the data from a SQL server, i have the e.NewValue and e.oldValue to determine which data was being modified/updated but i need to get the unique record ID which is store in "ID_ControlCharts" column

So, can you provide a code snippet/brief explanation in how to get the value from "ID_controlCharts" already filled by the gridview when i updated 1 cell (e.new/old)???

Note: The index is not what i needed since the row can be deleted and the reference to that row is now lost, so since the "ID_controlCharts" is filled automatically by SQL server key, its perfect for my situation.

codebehind

```
    If e.Equals("Control_SeqRef_CH") = False Then
        Dim oldvalue As String = e.OldValues("Control_SeqRef_CH")
        Dim newvalue As String = e.NewValues("Control_SeqRef_CH")
        Dim rowindex As Integer = e.RowIndex
        Dim IDfromcontrol as integer = ???

        MsgBox(oldvalue)
        MsgBox(newvalue)
        MsgBox(rowindex)
        Msgbox(IDfromcontrol)

    Else
        MsgBox("same")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

If the `ID_ControlCharts` column is in the record, couldn't you fetch it from e.OldValues?

```
Dim IDfromcontrol = e.OldValues("ID_ControlCharts")
```

Failing that, if you set `ID_ControlCharts` as a column for the `DataKeyNames` property, you should be able to fetch it using the `ItemIndex`:

```
Dim IDfromcontrol = GridView1.DataKeys(e.ItemIndex).Values(0)
```

(This is all from memory, so the syntax may be a little off.)

Comment: found the issue, the cell was set as Read Only and the e.oldvalues return nothing but when i removed the read only option the e.olvalues worked! Thank you!

Comment: Good!  Incidentally, your first line, where you compare `e` to the string "Control_SeqRef_CH", is always going to return false: `e` is never a string!  What were you trying to test there?

Comment: Actually i modified the code to jsut grab the old value (no comparison is made)... thank you for the heads up! :)